# How to avoid Overlapping with other element while dynamic adding and removing of textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, css-position

First of all i apologize for lengthy explanation.
I know this kind of question have answered so many times, and i have gone through some other post also,but none of the approach works for me.

Some where i am missing something, which i am not unable to fix this part.
It will great help if someone can point it out what exactly is going wrong.

Basically i have followed this link to start up to add and removing textarea dynamically:-

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

But i have modified the code as per my requirement.
i have attached 3 images to demonstrate what i was doing

[Click on this link to see the attached image this is by Default textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK7xi.png)

[On clicking +(plus) button i added new textarea,This is where textarea starts moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwGUy.png)

[Here when i added 3rd textarea add button position changed and text area were moved out and overlapped with label name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XczL7.png)

I tried by changing position and overflow,but nothing seems to work

Ok i am trying to fix this part of the code where i am having one default textarea and dynamically user can add and remove,but whenever i am trying to add new textarea, all previous textarea position is moving upwards and going beyond the range of this attribute

```
<td id="ui-selected-xpath">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
       <img class="add_field_button" src='images/new.png' width='16' height='16'/>
    <div class="ui-xpathDiv-forTextArea">
        <textarea id="xpathGrade" class="ui-xpath" type="text" name="mytext[]">
    </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

Now when i am dynamically adding the textarea, it is going beyond the td area

My HTML Code:-

```
<body>
    <div id='adding-app' title='Add New Xpath'>
        <div id='editor-app'></div>
        <div align='center'>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div id='tue' title='Add Xpath'>
                        <div id='editor-xpath'></div>
                        <div align='center'>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for='app_name0'><b>Xpath Request :
                                        </b></label>
                                        <p id="demo"></p>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id='Xpath' readonly></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="ui-selected-xpath">
                                        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                                            <img class="add_field_button" src='images/new.png' width='16' height='16'/>
                                            <div class="ui-xpathDiv">
                                                <textarea id="xpathGrade" class="ui-xpath" type="text" name="mytext[]">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my CSS Code:

```
#Xpath{
    width: 351px; 
    height: 349px;
}

#ui-selected-xpath{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.add_field_button{
    position: relative;
    float:left; 
    bottom:110px;
    left:266px;
}
.ui-xpath{
    position: relative;
    float:left; 
    bottom:135px;
    resize: none;
    height: 2em;
    width: 20em;
}
.ui-xpathDiv{
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
}
#xpathGrade{
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: none;
    height: 2em;
    width: 20em;
}
.ui-xpath{
    position: relative;
    float:left; 
    bottom:135px;
    resize: none;
    height: 2em;
    width: 20em;
}
```

My JS Code for adding and removing the textarea

```
$(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        isFirstElementFocused =false;
        x++; //text box increment
        $(".input_fields_wrap").append(
                '<div class="ui-xpathDiv" id="xpathDiv_'+x+'"><textarea id="xpathGrade_'+x+'" type="text" class="ui-xpath" name="mytext[]" /><img class="remove_field" src="images/remove.png"/></div>'
        ); 
    });

    $(".input_fields_wrap").on("click",".remove_field", 
        function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); 
            checkDuplicateXpath.remove($(this).prev().val());
            x--;
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
            $(".ui-xpathDiv").each(function () {
                x = Number(this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1));
            });
    });
```

What i am looking out is to make the dynamic textarea fixed so that whenever any textarea got added it should not move and it should append at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Your xpathGrade `textarea` is not being closed. e.g `<textarea id="xpathGrade" class="ui-xpath" type="text" name="mytext[]">` should be `<textarea id="xpathGrade" class="ui-xpath" type="text" name="mytext[]"></textarea>`. This could be whats causing the rendering error.

The textarea you are creating in your jQuery is also not being closed.

EDIT:

Try changing your CSS to this, as well as the textarea changes.

```
<style media="screen">
    #Xpath{
      width: 351px;
      height: 349px;
    }

    #ui-selected-xpath{
      border: 1px solid black;
      vertical-align:top;
    }

    #ui-selected-xpath img, #ui-selected-xpath textarea {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .add_field_button{
      position: relative;
    }
    .ui-xpath{
      position: relative;
      resize: none;
      height: 2em;
      width: 20em;
    }
    .ui-xpathDiv-forTextArea{
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      background-color: red;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    #xpathGrade{
      resize: none;
      height: 2em;
      width: 20em;
    }
    .ui-xpath{
      position: relative;
      resize: none;
      height: 2em;
      width: 20em;
    }
</style>
```

Also put that first image button inside the `ui-xpathDiv`.

```
<div class="ui-xpathDiv">
  <textarea id="xpathGrade" class="ui-xpath" type="text" name="mytext[]"></textarea>
  <img class="add_field_button" src='images/new.png' width='16' height='16'/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. The issue appears to be with the CSS.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer,the existing problem got solved, but now when i am dynamically adding new textarea both textarea defined in tr also start moving ,do you have idea how to fix the height of tr and stop expanding

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your updated code. It might be best to create a new question.